# "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'SMSMessage'"

Tags: python, class, object

I have tried many ways but can't seem to get the length of my list through the method in my class my code:

```
SMSStore = []
unreadMessage = []
class SMSMessage(object):

    def __init__(self, hasBeenRead, messageText, fromNumber):
        self.hasBeenRead = hasBeenRead
        self.messageText = messageText
        self.fromNumber = fromNumber
        hasBeenRead = False

    def markAsRead(self, hasBeenRead):
        hasBeenRead = True

    def add_sms(self):
        newMessage = (self.hasBeenRead, self.messageText, self.fromNumber)
        return SMSStore.append(newMessage)

    def get_count():
        return len(SMSStore)

    def get_message(self, i):
        hasBeenRead = True
        return SMSStore[i][1]

    def get_unread_messages(i):
        for i in SMSStore:
            if SMSStore[i][0] == False:
                unreadMessage.append(SMSStore[i])
        print unreadMessage

    def remove(self, i):
        return SMSStore.remove(i)
```

This is how a message in the list would ideally look like:

```
#sample = SMSMessage(False, "Hello friend!", 0742017560)
```

And here is how the class is used

```
userChoice = ""

while userChoice != "quit":
    userChoice = raw_input("What would you like to do - read/send/quit?")
    if userChoice == "read":
        print len(SMSStore)#this way i can get the length of the list anyway without using get_count
        SMSStore(get_count()

        unreadChoice = raw_input("Would you like to retrieve all unread messages or one of your own choice? - all unread/custom  ")
        if unreadChoice == "custom":                
            i = int(raw_input("Please enter which message number you want to read: "))
            print get_message(i)  #I dont understand how i works and how to get it working with the object definition

    elif userChoice == "send":
        messageText = raw_input("Please type in your message: ")
        fromNumber = raw_input("Please type in the number it was sent from ")
        newObject = SMSMessage(False, messageText, fromNumber)
        newObject.add_sms()

        print SMSStore

    elif userChoice == "quit":
        print "Goodbye"

    else:
        print "Oops - incorrect input"
```

I can just use `len(SMSStore)` but I want to be able to use the method inside the class to get it. Can point out any mistakes?

This was the question asked:

```
Open the file called​  sms.py​
Create a class definition for an SMSMessage which has three variables:
    hasBeenRead, messageText, and fromNumber.  
The constructor should initialise the sender’s number. 
The constructor should also initialise hasBeenRead  to false
Create a method in this class called MarkAsRead which should change hasBeenRead to true.
Create a list called SMSStore to be used as the inbox.

Then create the following methods:
add_sms - which takes in the text and number from the received sms to
          make a new SMSMessage object. 
get_count - returns the number of messages in the store.
get_message - returns the text of a message in the list.Forthis, allow the
              user to input an index i.e. GetMessage(i) returns the message
              stored at position i in the list. Once this has been done,
              hasBeenRead should now be true. 
get_unread_messages - should return a list of all the messages which
                      haven’t been read. 
remove - removes a message in the SMSStore. 
Now that you have these set up, let’s get everything working!
```

Comment: This is the question:

Comment: ● Open the file called​  sms.py

Comment: ● Create a class definition for an SMSMessage which has three variables:                       hasBeenRead, messageText, and fromNumber.

Comment: ● The constructor should initialise the sender’s number.

Comment: ● The constructor should also initialise hasBeenRead  to false

Comment: ● Create a method in this class called MarkAsRead which should change                       hasBeenRead to true.

Comment: ● Create a list called SMSStore to be used as the inbox.

Comment: Then create the following methods:

Comment: add_sms - which takes in the text and number from the received sms to                             make a new SMSMessage object.

Comment: not here edit your origin question and add the info to it

Comment: ○ get_count - returns the number of messages in the store.

Comment: The first line of your code is indented. That is incorrect and should cause an error.

Comment: copy paste error, but that aint the problem

Answer (score 0):

in your SMSMessage class

```
def get_count(self, *args):
    return len(SMSStore)
```

in your script

```
# create instance
sms_msg = SMSMessage() # init arg needed
print sms_msg.get_count()
```

SMSStore is a global variable, you could remove get_count from SMSMessage scope

```
SMSStore = []
unreadMessage = []
class SMSMessage(object):
    ...functions...

def get_count(*args):
    return len(SMSStore)
```

and call it regularly OR

```
ls = range(20)

class A(object):
  # declare default value for your arguments
  def __init__(self, hasBeenRead = False, messageText = "", fromNumber=0):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
  #using classmethod 
  @classmethod
  def get_count(cls, *args):
    return len(ls)


print A.get_count()
```

Comment: Thanks, althought i get an error " TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given) "

Comment: I understand that, but i am doing a task and i am required to do it as they said, can i post the question?

Comment: i am unfamiliar with the second part with class message, but when i tried this SMSStore = []
unreadMessage = []
class SMSMessage(object):
    ...functions...

def get_count(*args):
    return len(SMSStore)

Comment: when i tried your first solution i still get the error; i am using this: SMSStore.get_count() to call it

Comment: SMSStore is a list object......it has no build-in method called get_count()...so it will fail always,.....i realize you need really check the basics, create a simple class and try your questions on it......

Comment: My tutor recommended i use the SMSSTore.get_count() , so unless there is another way or something i am missing, and yes i am very new to this